# How to decrease request payload of p:ajax during e.g. p:dataTable pagination

Tags: ajax, performance, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am using JSF 2.2 with Primefaces 5.1. There is an editable primefaces datatable with pagination enabled.

```
            <p:dataTable editMode="row" 
                         editable="true" 
                         value="#{usersBean.users}" 
                         var="user" paginator="true" rows="20">

                <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" onstart="handleRowEditInit(event,this);"/>

                <p:column>
                    <p:rowEditor/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Real name">
                    <p:cellEditor rendered="true">
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{user.realName}"/>
      </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.realName}"/>
                            </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="User name">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{user.userName}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Every time the page is changed the datatable does an AJAX POST with all the data of the current page. As you can partly see in the image below.

[image]

For big tables with much data this results in huge requests. This is not neccessary right? Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, when you submit a form in HTML, by default every single HTML input element will be sent as request parameter. PrimeFaces ajax components therefore offer the `partialSubmit="true"` attribute which will then send **only** the HTML input elements covered by the `process` attribute, which defaults in `<p:ajax>` to `@this` and in `<p:commandXxx>` to `@form`.

So, just add this to the data table in case to optimize pagination performance:

```html
<p:ajax event="page" partialSubmit="true" />
```

And add this to any command button which only needs to access the current row in the data table (e.g. to show it in a dialog) to optimize action processing performance:

```html
<p:commandButton ... process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />
```

You can also configure it globally via below context param in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
    <param-value>partial</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then for cases where you actually need a full submit, explicitly use `partialSubmit="false"`.

Comment: @BaslusC I have a `h:form` around `p:dataTable` and `p:dialog`. Within the data table, I have an `p:ajax` event registered on clicking on a single row to show that dialog box. Will this change also affect performance of such requests? No editing of page rows here.