# Conditionally apply AJAX events to datatable rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm relatively new to JSF and Primefaces, but I've been tasked to try and reduce the amount of AJAX requests made in a legacy codebase. This question is from a particular example where we have a directory listing UI of files and folders.

```
<p:dataTable id="directoryTable" var="directoryObject" value="#{fileCabinet.folderContents}" 
    resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true"
    rowKey="#{directoryObject}" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{fileCabinet.currentObject}" dblClickSelect="true"
    sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage="This folder is empty"
    sortFunction="#{dataTableUtil.sort}">  

    <c:if test="#{directoryObject.objectType eq 'DIRECTORY'}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{fileCabinet.onRowSelect}"   
                            update=":form:directoryTable :menu" />                              
    </c:if>
```

I've excluded the rest of the datatable for brevity. With this code, the ajax event is *never* attached even though the 'test' expression evaluates perfectly fine in subsequent 'rendered' attributes of html elements later on. Unfortunately, p:ajax doesn't support 'rendered' conditionals.

I've also tried c:choose / c:when, to the same results.

This feels like something that should be really easy to do! I'm probably missing some simple syntax to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: As to why the `<c:if>` failed, head to this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3442380

Comment: As to performance trouble, don't forget to look at `partialSubmit`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30934671

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by using the `disabled` attribute for `<p:ajax>` with my conditional as the value (negated of course).

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
        listener="#{fileCabinet.onRowSelect}"   
        update=":form:directoryTable :menu" 
        disabled="#{directoryObject.objectType ne 'DIRECTORY'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.0 version, Primefaces datatable comes with a disabledSelection property.

```
<p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{bean.foos}" selection="#{bean.selectedFoo}" disabledSelection="#{foo.bar == 1}">
    <p:column selectionMode="single" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" />
    </p:column>
<p:dataTable>
```