# PrimeFaces Extensions pe:sheet component live scroll

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Is live scroll possible in pe:sheet component primefaces. For datatable I had performed live scroll and it was working.

Any work around for live scroll in pe:sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the component and I can answer that there is no LiveScroll of the sheet.

That being said...The sheet was meant to handle a large volume of data and when you make edits it only submits the single cell you edited, unlike the PF DataTable which submits the whole form.

I would say give it a try to see if it meets your needs.  How many rows are you trying to load?

Comment: _"unlike the PF DataTable which submits the whole form"_ does it? sure there is no 'partialSubmit' for '@this'???

Comment: Well what I meant was if you have a datatable with all celleditors and they are all open and you Submit your form it submits all the cells in the datatable.  So if you trying to create a "spreadsheet" like function using the datatable where every cell is editable.

Comment: You mean if you have celleditors period (you cannot have multiple open) and you submit from one of them, all are submitted? That is true but IIRC, you can circumvent this with `<p:ajax event="cellEdit" partialSubmit="true">` or settting partialSubmit to true on a global basis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934671/how-to-decrease-request-payload-of-pajax-during-e-g-pdatatable-pagination (which I do by default) or even use `o:form` for that http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form

Comment: Sorry what I mean to say is if you have a table with 4 columns and 10 rows with an `p:inputText` NOT a cellEditor.  Users when editing a "sheet" don't want to have to click on each cell to turn it to an editor to then edit it.  They want "Excel like editing". PF DT submits 40 values (4 x10 = 40). Now imagine 10x10 or 10x200 rows. You can't make an Excel like interface using the DataTable.  A lot of user don't want to click on a row to make it editable they want to TAB around cells.  At least a lot of my users do.  The Sheet was designed for that style interface for quick data entry.

Comment: I was just talking about the submitting (as was you), not the usability. I agree that the sheet is much better for this!

Comment: Thanks @Melloware . tried by loading 1Lac rows data set it is working fine with 10 columns , let me try with the actual data . for persisting of the data is there any example which will help me out !!!

Comment: Yes look at this example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf  You can see each update is sent to the backing bean which you can collect. You can save it immediately or wait until they press "Save" and save all the updates at once.

Comment: @Melloware sheet is not loading more than 1Lac records , and not sure why my method is called twice on the p:tab

Comment: 2 different issue.  When you say 1 Lac you mean 100,000 records right?  Second issue about Tab is completely unrelated try to stay on this topic. 100,000 rows with 10 columns is 1 million data points going to the UI.  I have never tested with this much data as ours usually less than that.   Not sure what the underlying Handsontable can handle as far as max rows.

Comment: @Melloware . Let me give a try and i will share you the result . it might be helpfull for others

Comment: Great idea.  Let me know how it goes

Comment: hi @Melloware ,sorry for the delay . had tested with 2M data points it is working . it is loading in 1 Min 43 secs . need to some clarification on rowkey , why is it mandatory in sheet which is not a mandate in datatable

Comment: Rowkey is mandatory on sheet because when you edit cell rows we have to be able to uniquely identify which row was edited.

Comment: Thanks @Melloware , Any predefined export options for pe:sheet or is it in development which will be released soon !!

Comment: Do you mean like export to CSV or XLSX?

Comment: Yes @Melloware , any option for export !!

Comment: Nothing planned as of right now but I may add it as a future enhancement.